# How to move iMacro script to Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, migration, imacros

We have been using iMacro for our QA Automation, at a recent discussion it was decided to shift to Selenium.

Selenium provides a comparison thus neglected to mention how to migrate scripts to their platform..http://wiki.imacros.net/Selenium

is there any tools available for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no tool that I know of that can help you with this.

There a couple of alternatives for migrating from iMacros to Selenium:

1. If you have a small amount of scripts re-record them using selenium IDE
2. If you have a large amount of test you could write a script that can map equivalent commands, you may still need to do some manual clean up but it may at least save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (if you are using firefox) is to select Tools->Selenium IDE.  This will open Selenium IDE in a separate window.  Use the Imacros sidebar to "play" the script while Selenium IDE is recording.  I just did this myself.  It works like a charm.  Obviously,  this won't do any Imacros specific text-scraping,  but if your script is a simple set of actions it works fabulously.